# how to bring back my first scene indicator arrow?

Tags: ios, objective-c

my first scene indicator arrow disappeared...I dont know how, but the arrow I had in the first view controller that should be initiated is gone, how do I bring it back?

tnx

Answer (score 1):

You need to set "Is initial View Controller".
Check the screenshot:

[image]